# Wildcards inside quotes

Tags: shell, wildcards, quoting

This will be an easy one, but in my memories, when shell scripting, using double quotes would allow expanding globbing and variables.

But in the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo *.sh
echo "*.sh"
echo '*.sh'

echo $LANG
echo "$LANG"
echo '$LANG'
```

I get this result:

```
bob.sh redeployJboss.sh
*.sh
*.sh
en_US.utf8
en_US.utf8
$LANG
```

So single quoting prevent glob AND variable expansion but double quoting allows only variable expansion and no globbing?

Can I glob in any quoting pattern?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You are correct: globbing doesn't work in either single- or double-quotes.  However, you can interpolate globbing with double-quoted strings:

```
$ echo "hello world" *.sh "goodbye world"
hello world [list of files] goodbye world
```

Comment: Or even `echo "$hello and $goodbye".*` (mix variable expansions, spaces, and a glob in the same "word".

Comment: Globbing doesn't seem to work in this case, `echo /path/to/file/*${variable}`. How do I glob while appending an interpolated email?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai `echo "$FOLDER_PATH"/*.extension` works fine for me, contrary to the accepted answer, I had to remove the whitespace between the `"` and the `*`. Hope it helps.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, @LostBalloon I use the following pattern when I want to use globs with variables that may have spaces: `(cd "$FOLDER_PATH" && echo *.extension)`