# Using the * variable in a shell script to to refer to all files in a folder

Tags: bash, shell-script

I was just writing a bash script to execute and I tried to cp some files from within the script; eg

`cp "myfolder/*.*" "otherfolder"`

and it complained that "myfolder/*.*" could not be found.
Then I tried this to be more specific

`cp "myfolder/*.ini" "otherfolder"`

still complaining.

then I tried

`cp "myfolder/${*}.ini" "otherfolder"`

still complaining; all this did was put the command line arguments in this place with .ini suffix.

`cp "myfolder/{*}.ini" "otherfolder"`

Still no success. So just ended putting in the full file names for each file and it worked. But is there a way to use the asterisk in a bash file to refer to all files in the directory? 
Or can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: See [Wildcards inside quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67757/wildcards-inside-quotes)

Comment: to refer al files in the directory, I think `cp myDirectory/*` is enough.

Comment: and @Charles too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filename globbing patterns will not be expanded by the shell if you quote them (this is one of the reasons you *do* want to quote variable expansions in general, especially if they hold values that could be interpreted as globbing patterns).

Instead of

```
cp "myfolder/*.*" "otherfolder"
```

you should use

```sh
cp "myfolder"/*.* "otherfolder"
```

This would copy anything that has a name with a dot in it in `myfolder` to `otherfolder` (assuming `otherfolder` is the name of a directory).  Note that the `*` pattern does not match hidden filenames by default and that most shells would leave the pattern *unexpanded* if no filename matched it.

Likewise, `cp "myfolder/*.ini" "otherfolder"` should have been written `cp "myfolder"/*.ini "otherfolder"`.

The `$*` *variable* is quite another thing from the `*` globbing pattern and the two are not really related.  The string `"$*"` will be the concatenation of the positional variables (the "command line arguments", `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, ...), delimited by the first character of the shell variable `IFS` (which by default is a space).

Comment: Awesome answer @Kusalananda. Thankyou.