# Using bash wildcards with filenames that have single-quotes

Tags: bash, filenames, wildcards, wget

I used `wget` within bash to download a bunch of files from a parameterized URL.  My URL file looked something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/Home/Sales?lrsn=48726
http://www.example.com/Home/Sales?lrsn=48727
http://www.example.com/Home/Sales?lrsn=48728
...and so on
```

I ran this wget command to fetch all the files into my directory:

```
wget -i urlfile.txt
```

The resulting set of files-- when I do an `ls` in my directory-- has names like this:

```
'Sales?lrsn=48726'
'Sales?lrsn=48727'
'Sales?lrsn=48728'
```

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to use wildcards with those files.  E.g., if I type `ls 'Sales*8'`, I would expect it to list `'Sales?lrsn=48728'` (and any other matches).  Instead, I get "No such file or directory".

**Questions:**

1. What do I need to do to use wildcards with the files that my `wget` operation created? Simple example would be how to match using `ls`.
2. How would one even create such files to reproduce this.  I.e., I tried `touch 'text.txt'` and `touch "'test.txt'"` and other variations, but I can't seem to make a file that lists as `'test.txt'` (starting and ending single-quotes).
3. Is there a simple way to provide a naming convention for downloads using the `wget -i` input mode? (I'm pretty sure the answer to this is "No," but... figured I'd ask.)

Comment: Okay, it looks like the `'` are being shown in the `ls` results because of the `?` and `=` signs that appear in the filenames.  So I actually can do the wildcards if I do something like `ls Sales\?lrsn\=48*`.  So I might have answered my own question after spending that time writing it up.

Comment: [Why is 'ls' suddenly wrapping items with spaces in single quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/258679/108618)

Comment: [Wildcards inside quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/67757/108618).